# `conda init powershell` result in a strange character

Tags: python, powershell, conda

Command `conda init powershell` add the current python env name in front prompt, but there is also a strange character '' in front of base, how to remove it?

```bsh
PowerShell 7.1.0-preview.3
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.

   base  ~\..\..\Python  ipython
Python 3.7.7 (default, May  6 2020, 11:45:54) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 7.16.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: ord('')
Out[1]: 58886

In [2]:
```

`conda init powershell` result:

```bsh
⨯  ~\..\..\Python  conda init powershell
no change     C:\Python\Scripts\conda.exe
no change     C:\Python\Scripts\conda-env.exe
no change     C:\Python\Scripts\conda-script.py
no change     C:\Python\Scripts\conda-env-script.py
no change     C:\Python\condabin\conda.bat
no change     C:\Python\Library\bin\conda.bat
no change     C:\Python\condabin\_conda_activate.bat
no change     C:\Python\condabin\rename_tmp.bat
no change     C:\Python\condabin\conda_auto_activate.bat
no change     C:\Python\condabin\conda_hook.bat
no change     C:\Python\Scripts\activate.bat
no change     C:\Python\condabin\activate.bat
no change     C:\Python\condabin\deactivate.bat
no change     C:\Python\Scripts\activate
no change     C:\Python\Scripts\deactivate
no change     C:\Python\etc\profile.d\conda.sh
no change     C:\Python\etc\fish\conf.d\conda.fish
no change     C:\Python\shell\condabin\Conda.psm1
no change     C:\Python\shell\condabin\Conda.psm1
no change     C:\Python\shell\condabin\conda-hook.ps1
no change     C:\Python\Lib\site-packages\xontrib\conda.xsh
no change     C:\Python\etc\profile.d\conda.csh
modified      %USERPROFILE%\Documents\PowerShell\profile.ps1
modified      %USERPROFILE%\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\profile.ps1

==> For changes to take effect, close and re-open your current shell. <==
```

These two modifications are

```
#region conda initialize
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
(& "C:\Python\Scripts\conda.exe" "shell.powershell" "hook") | Out-String | Invoke-Expression
#endregion
```

Comment: `ord('')` is getting the ascii for the _replacement_ character in the terminal. Try `conda init powershell > outshell.txt` and check the output file.

Comment: Two factors are at play: (1) What character encoding `conda.exe` uses for its output. (2) What `[console]::OutputEncoding]` is set to, which by default corresponds to the active legacy OEM code page (`chcp`) - this is how PowerShell will interpret the output.